# Opening IIS on windows server 2012 as normal user with local admin rights

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I have this scenario:
I have IIS which is installed on windows 2012 R2.
I have a local admin in this machine which is used to open the service and work on the site.
There are some users which can rdp to this machine and open IIS as Users, which means they do not have full permission on that service
i have created script from them to run as user which open the IIS manager which permission of local admin. problem is i cannot hide the credentials of the local admin and i do not want users to have it.
Is there any way i can make that thing happen without showing creds in script? (compile to exe doesnt help me as this is easly decompile back to script)

Comment: yes, read this https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/

Comment: This is useless since user can read the script and manipulate it so he can read the password in clear text even if encrypted

Comment: he can decrypt the secure string that is true, but you say in your question "without showing creds in script" which we wouldn't in this case. I don't even know if powershell ever uses anything else than a secure.string for passwords, even if you would use the vault. you'll have to wait for someone that can tell you this.

Comment: yes that the problem. since he has access to the script he can manipulate it and use the credentials (even if he wont have the password itself), he can write another script doing whatever he want using the local admin credentials.. and thats something i want to avoid from

Comment: Store needed elevated creds in Windows Credential Manager and call them from your script as needed. No matter where you store creds, if you allow a user to use them, and they are so inclined and skilled enough to do so, then, they can be retrieved and be used for other purposes even in an encrypted string. This is not unique to PowerShell. If you don't trust the user to use their access appropriately (then don’t allow it), then you have bigger issues. Your only other option is using PowerShell JEA and constrained endpoints. So, they can only run specific commands on a given host.

Comment: Thank you both B>

Answer (score 1):

You can give users or groups permission to IIS manager sites/applications. From [MS TechCommunity link:](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/manage-iis-locally-with-a-non-admin-account/ba-p/1006358)

> The following steps are for a website. You can use similar steps for
> applications.
>
> 1. Open IIS Manager
> 2. Click the website
> 3. Double click “IIS Manager Permissions”
> 4. Click “Allow User”. Add your domain or local users

And even allow them to connect remotely instead of using RDP:

> For managing application pools with a non-admin user remotely, add users to [IIS Manager Permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7#configure-iis-manager-permissions-for-a-site-or-an-application) (just like we did above). Then go to “IIS Manager > Management Service” and enable it. After this change, you can open IIS Manager in another server and add this server as a new connection

As you suspected, saving credentials is not a good option.

Comment: Question is- will they be able to restart the IIS Service? i need them to be able to do that

Comment: @ShaharWeiss In the past, I've created a scheduled task that restarts the service as an admin, and only give other users permissions to run it.

Comment: Thats is a GREAT idea! thank you!